# Deny folder access to specific users

Tags: cmd, permissions, folder-permissions

I am looking for a command in cmd that will deny access to a certain folder to all users except for a specific one. I've tried with `icacls` but I couldn't do that.

Comment: Try with `cacls`: `for %A IN ("user1" "user2" "user3") do @cacls C:\testfolder /e /c /d %~A`. To allow access, add `:f` to the end. Please note that `user1`, `user2`, e.t.c are the users that won't have access to this folder. Is it working?

Comment: Would you mind showing your attempt?

Comment: @double-beep, thanks for the reply but my goal is to block access to every user (I dont know the names of all of them) except one (myself).. Is there a way to block access to all existing users and to new ones in the future?

Comment: @LeeWyi perhaps `for /F "delims=" %%A IN ('dir /b C:\Users') do cacls C:\testfolder /e /c /d %%A 2>nul`

Comment: @double-beep yes that's exactly what I needed! Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible and can be done with the `cacls` command in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```bat
for %A IN ("user1" "user2" "user3" "user4") do @cacls C:\some\folder /e /c /d %~A
```

where to allow access to these users to a certain folder again use:

```bat
for %A IN ("user1" "user2" "user3" "user4") do @cacls C:\some\folder /e /c /d %~A:f
```

Be sure to replace `user1`, `user2`, e.t.c. with the actual, correct usernames and add more if you want. You will need also to change `C:\some\folder` to the actual folder path.

For a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) solution, double the percent-signs like this:

```bat
@for %%A IN ("user1" "user2" "user3" "user4") do @cacls C:\some\folder /e /c /d %%~A:f
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. My main goal is to block access to everyone without knowing their names/logins and give access to only one specific user who has login=admin.. Is there a way to do this with icacls?